# 'as much as 100 mph' or 'as many as 100 mph'?

Tags: usage

> *Nowadays my pitches are hitting *****as much as***** 100 mph.*
>
> vs.
>
> *Nowadays my pitches are hitting *****as many as***** 100 mph.*

Which is right? I googled but couldn't find any results.

Answer (score 1):

**mph**, or "**Miles per Hour**" is a unit of measuring **speed**.  **Speed** is an uncountable noun.  Uncountable nouns such as **speed** (or **water**) never use "many".

> Nowadays my pitches are hitting as much as 100 mph.

This is correct.

> Nowadays my pitches are hitting as many as 100 mph.

This is incorrect.

(Never say "as many as 100mL water" either.)